# vbscript: convert unicode string to array of bytes

Tags: vbscript, automation, type-conversion

I have unicode string passed to vbscript procedure (not visual basic 6, but vbscript). I want to iterate unicode string char by char, get code for every symbol, truncate code to byte range [0..255] and create array of bytes.

This way new array of bytes should be twice smaller in memory compared to original unicode string. I am going save this array to file via [ADODB.Stream](http://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_read-write-binary-files/) object further

How can I convert unicode string to bytes array with symbol code truncated to byte range?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is no way to create array of bytes in vbs (though it's very straightforward in visual basic) -- all arrays are arrays of variants.

The task was to send binary stream from server to vbs script via string type. I have found the solution by creating Xml Document on the server with CDATA section that contains base64 coded array of bytes as string data.

Client (vbs) do the following:

```
set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XmlDom")
xmlDoc.loadXML(dataFromServer)
base64str = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.Text  ' it's base64 coded binary stream
arrayOfBytes = decodeBase64(base64str)

Function decodeBase64(base64)  
  set dm = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
  set el = dm.createElement("tmp")
  el.DataType = "bin.base64"
  el.Text = base64
  decodeBase64 = el.NodeTypedValue
  set dm = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, translating unicode to ascii will only work if your string only contains ascii characters. Since unicode contains ascii, it is just a matter of removing every second character.

Look up unicode on the internet for details.

EDIT: In unicode, every ascii character is proceeded with a NULL (0) byte. Remove this byte to convert the string to ASCII.

Comment: Thank you for the response but there is no CharW function in vbs. I found walkaround how to create array of bytes in vbs I would describe in a few days

Answer (score 2):

This function creates an array of bytes:

```
' http://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_binarytostring/
Function MultiByteToBinary(MultiByte)
  '� 2000 Antonin Foller, http://www.motobit.com
  ' MultiByteToBinary converts multibyte string To real binary data (VT_UI1 | VT_ARRAY)
  ' Using recordset
  Dim RS, LMultiByte, Binary
  Const adLongVarBinary = 205
  Set RS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
  LMultiByte = LenB(MultiByte)
  If LMultiByte>0 Then
    RS.Fields.Append "mBinary", adLongVarBinary, LMultiByte
    RS.Open
    RS.AddNew
      RS("mBinary").AppendChunk MultiByte & ChrB(0)
    RS.Update
    Binary = RS("mBinary").GetChunk(LMultiByte)
  End If
  MultiByteToBinary = Binary
End Function
```

This function creates a multi-byte string.

```
' http://www.motobit.com/help/regedit/pa26.htm
'Converts unicode string to a multibyte string
Function StringToMB(S)
  Dim I, B
  For I = 1 To Len(S)
    B = B & ChrB(Asc(Mid(S, I, 1)))
  Next
  StringToMB = B
End Function
```